# Conversion tracking AdWords iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-ads-api

I'm wondering if I understood it right, that it isn't possible to track whether an iOS-App-Installation were made because of an ad or because of another reason. We have an AdWord campaign and want to see, when a installation were made from our ads. The implemented code is the following:

```
[ACTAutomatedUsageTracker enableAutomatedUsageReportingWithConversionID:@"xxxxxx"];

[ACTConversionReporter reportWithConversionID:@"xxxxxx" label:@"yyyyyy" value:@"0.00" isRepeatable:NO];
```